# Jquery Ajax request is wrong - something is missing or incorrect

Tags: jquery

Below is the function that makes the ajax call in question.  Here are the parameters that are being plugged in, as given by the javascript debugger in Firefox:

```
JSON.stringify(c) =    {"start":0,"length":20,"sortBy":"dc","sortAscending":false,"providerId":128391,"currencyIds":[],"fromDateStr":"2007-01-01","toDateStr":"2014-01-10","validTrades":true,"lotSize":2}

b.resolveUrl(e)   =   "http://localhost/j1/test/proxy.php"
g = [object Window]
b = [object Object]
a.isFunction(d) && d.call(g, c, f, g) = false
```

The Function:

```
a.ajax(a.extend({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(c),
        url: b.resolveUrl(e),
        context: g,
        cache: !1,
        success: function (c, e, d) {
            a.isFunction(f) &&
                f.call(g, "undefined" != typeof c.d ? b.parseJSON(c.d) : c, g, e, d)
        },
        error: function (b, c, f) {
            a.isFunction(d) && d.call(g, c, f, g)
        }
    }, h))
```

Why is this going to error?  What's wrong?  I have inserted the following at the beginning of the proxy.php file to make sure that the data is posting correctly:

```
if(empty($_POST)) die("POST failed!");
```

In the response of the request I see "POST failed!" message.

Comment: Try simplifying your ajax request to see if you can get it working. `$.ajax({type:'POST',data:'testing', url:'/j1/test/proxy.php'})`. Then begin adding the rest of your ajax options until it breaks again

Comment: I don't think `data` expects a stringified object. Try a plain json object, or a querystring (`val=bla&foo=bar`). However, if the request does work as-is, then PHP wouldn't be able to parse it into the `$_POST` array, try getting the raw post value (`http_get_request_body()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're posting `json` rather than form-encoded data. This means PHP can't extract the data and put it in `$_POST` which will consequently be empty.

If your data was sent correctly, you should be able to get it from `http_get_request_body()` and decode it with `json_decode()` (set the second argument to true if you want an associative array instead of an object)

If you want to receive the data in `$_POST`, then don't apply `JSON.stringify` to the data on the client side. jQuery is quite happy to form-encode an object.